# Difference between instance_eval and singleton method

Tags: ruby

Singleton method is a method that is defined only on one instance.

```
foo = Foo.new
def foo.case
  #singleton method
end
```

Doesn't `instance_eval` do the same thing? Defining a method for a particular instance? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The metaprogramming tool `instance_eval` does the same thing right? Defining a method for a particular instance?

No. `instance_eval` has nothing whatsoever to do with defining methods. It evaluates a block in the context of the receiver. Normally, blocks are lexically scoped, including `self`, a block that is evaluated using `instance_eval` is evaluated with `self` bound to the receiver of the message.

```
one = Object.new
two = Object.new

def one.my_eval; yield end

instance_variables
# => []

one.my_eval { @ivar_one = 1 }

one.instance_variables
# => []

instance_variables
# => [:@ivar_one]

two.instance_eval { @ivar_two = 2 }

two.instance_variables
# => [:@ivar_two]
```

> So what is really the difference?

They are completely unrelated. It doesn't really make sense to ask about the difference between two unrelated things.

Answer (score 4):

[Object#`instance_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval) is a method, using which you indeed can define method for an object.

Singleton class is a "place", where the singleton method defined for the object "lives".

So these are two absolutely different things.

Comment: @mhaseeb Absolutely right. *singleton class*, *eigen class*, *metaclass* -   these all are the different names of one thing.